# vb.net console / service app

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, console-application

I'd like to enable my console app. to be installed also as a service using command prompt arguments, handling the following commands

> d\:>myapp -console
>   d\:>myapp -install
>   d\:>myapp -uninstall

My vb.net service template is as follows,

```
Public Class MyService
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
        ' in motion so your service can do its work.
    End Sub  
End Class
```

How I should proceed to run it as console and/or console.

Thanks in advance,
m0dest0

Ps. using vb.net and Vs 2008

Ps2. The kind of taks to be performed is suitable to be implemented either in console or service. Basically it will monitor files in a specific folder and the process the info.

Comment: You want to call the console app and tell it to install as a Windows Service or run as a console app?  I'm not sure you can do that - it may be an either/or.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable, I have a service that does this very thing.

The main business logic should be encapsulated such that it can be run (launched as a thread) from within the Service or from a shared sub Main.

You will need to add a service installer if there is not one already, but the VS template adds that for you so you should be all set.

In your Main, you have to parse the command line (obviously) and execute the appropriate action.  I would recommend, for one-stop-shopping, adding a -start and -stop command line option as well to stop and start the service.